# Redirecting old URLs to new ones after migrating to Sitecore

Tags: redirect

We are working on migration project where we are migrating from legacy CMS system to Sitecore 8.2 and we are migrating around 300  pages to Sitecore

One of the requirement where we have  is to Redirect users accessing some of the URL's from this external system to new system when this new System goes live.

Redirection would be something like this
Legacy URL : http://old_domain/en/press/pressreleases/10-16-2017/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX

New URL : http://new_domain/en/press/PressReleases/2017/October/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.

Can some body guide me how do i do this.

Comment: Answer might lie here: https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/10709/implement-subdomain-redirects-while-using-sitecore-url-rewrite-module

Answer (score 1):

As Mark has said the Sitecore URL rewrite module is what is recommended for this:

https://marketplace.sitecore.net/Modules/Url_Rewrite.aspx
https://github.com/iamandycohen/UrlRewrite

This module is similar to IIS rewrite rules and supports regex etc, however the re-write rules exist in Sitecore instead of in a web.config / redirects file.

I've used this before to great success as it is pretty flexible so should handle most scenarios. It also gives content editors visibility over what rules are in place which is much better than something hidden away that they can't see.

I also developed a tool for importing a spreadsheet that contained the old an new urls and it auto-created the re-write url items for you. This saves a lot of time and user error when there are lots of urls to re-write. It supported multi-site too.

I will perhaps look to re-work it and make it available on the marketplace/github if this is something that would be useful to others.

Comment: My question if redirection has to be done from legacy system which is in other domain how could rules be placed in new domain as request will first go to legacy system and from there redirection will happen.

Comment: Also to test we would need test instance of legacy system so that rules could be tested before we go live

Comment: So what you would normally do is point the old domain at Sitecore at the point of switchover (lets say www.myolddomain.com) and then the re-write rule in sitecore will look for www.myolddomain.com/my-url-1 and will be setup to re-direct to: www.mynewdomain.com/myurl1. Make sense?

Comment: to test this you could just setup an test host entry on a dev environment with sitecore installed and your old cms system and check everything works before deploying to UAT/Prod

Comment: Got it but point of switch over is on the day of go live to test this do we need to point the QA domain of legacy system to QA instance of Sitecore.

Comment: Yes thats how I'd approach it to test things.

Comment: To point legacy QA System to new one do I need to change dns mapping or I could just put rule in IIS

Comment: It depends, if it is a local dns that would be the best idea. Otherwise you could put a host-hack on the QA server(s) perhaps. It depends on your setup. You will obviously need the right bindings in iss too for your domains.