# Implement domain redirects while using sitecore URL Rewrite module

Tags: redirect, url-rewrite

[In this post](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/10709/implement-subdomain-redirects-while-using-sitecore-url-rewrite-module) we have successfully implemented the subdomain redirect so now I'm going to implement domain redirect itself.

Entered URL: www.mysite.com

Expected URL: www.samplesite.com/about/history

First of all we have to change DNS mapping of **www.mysite.com** URL so that this can start pointing to **www.samplesite.com** Load balancer IP address so basically CNAME for **www.mysite.com** should start pointing to **www.samplesite.com**

Do I need to follow the same process for domain redirect which I followed for sub-domain redirect [in this post](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/10709/implement-subdomain-redirects-while-using-sitecore-url-rewrite-module)
OR I need to make some change in Inbound/Outbound rules

Thanks

Comment: I dont think this has much to do with sitecore. I would just do it in IIS https://weblogs.asp.net/owscott/iis-url-rewrite-redirect-multiple-domain-names-to-one

Comment: I agree, this relates to things not having anything to do with Sitecore.

Comment: @DylanYoung
this is related to Sitecore itself because we are using Sitecore URL Rewrite module... if you see I did set up sub-domain redirect in https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/10709/implement-subdomain-redirects-while-using-sitecore-url-rewrite-module and now I need to set up domain redirect

Comment: @Sukhjeevan if you already set up Subdomain-Redirects you can also do Domain redirects with Inbound rules.

Comment: @monkey.dsc okay I'll follow the same process for this as well...I was thinking in case any other work-around might be needed due to Domian redirects...